# Sort Django objects by attribute in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model, Item, with several attributes such as name, type, and owner. In my template the list of Items is iterated through and displayed in a table. What I would like to do is reorder the items in the table when a button next to the table head is clicked i.e. when the button next to Name is clicked the elements in the table are sorted by alphabetical order. Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'inventory/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'inventory:entry' %}">New Item</a>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
</script>
{% if item_list %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name <button class="btn btn-default" href="order_table"></button></th>
            <th>Type <button class="btn btn-default" href="order_table"></button></th>
            <th>Barcode/Model No. <button class="btn btn-default" href="order_table"></button></th>
            <th>Owner <button class="btn btn-default" href="order_table"></button></th>
            <th>Edit <button class="btn btn-default" href="order_table"></button></th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in item_list %}
            <tr class="clickable-row itemrow" data-href="{% url 'inventory:details' item.id %}">
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.itemType }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.barcode }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.owner.username }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'inventory:edit' item.id %}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Well you have two options; use Javascript to sort the items directly on the page, or pass the sort parameter to the server and redo the query there with sorting.

Comment: If I were to pass a sort parameter to the server is there a way that I could reload only the table portion of the page and not the entire page?

Comment: Sure, you can do that with Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of a button use a link and pass a parameter to the view:

```
<th><a href="{{ url('myurl') }}?sort=name">Name </a></th>
```

in the django view you can retrieve the sort parameter using : `request.GET.get('sort', 'your_default_sort')` and use it to order the queryset. If you're using FBV change it manually in the function, and if you're using CBV just override the `get_ordering()` method of your class

however, It would me much much easier with a client-side solution like [datatables](https://datatables.net/)

Hope this helps